# My Xpaths don't work in Scrapy Splash, but work in Selenium

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to scrape a list all of the scholarships in the https://bigfuture.collegeboard.org/scholarships/; I was able to scrape all of the links and store it in a list using Selenium. However, Selenium is not scalable to scrape the data in each web address. I am trying to use Scrapy and Splash, but using the Xpath or the CSS selector don't work. This is my first time webscraping so I am very lost. I would greatly appreciate any help!

```
class ScholarshipSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scholarship'
    start_urls = [line.strip() for line in open("links.txt")]
    
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, args={'wait': 7, 'html': 1, 'png': 1})

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ScholarshipSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.items_list = []
        
    def parse(self, response):
        
        item = {
            'name': response.xpath('//*[@id="main-content"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/section[1]/div/div[1]/h1/text()').get()

            #other items here
        }
        
        self.logger.info(item) 
        self.items_list.append(item)
        
        print(f"Name: {item['name']}") 
        
    def closed(self, reason):
        df = pd.DataFrame(self.items_list)
        df.to_csv('scraped_data.csv', index=False)
```

When I tried using Selenium, Xpaths worked, but my code stopped to work after a while. Scrapy seems like the best alternative but doesn't matter what I try, it does not work.

I am using Jupyter Notebook btw.

Comment: Do you get any error? What do you meqn by not working? Note that you can use python virtual environment and `pip` package manager instead of Jupyter notebook.

Comment: I mean that my xpaths results return as "None." Sorry for not explaining it better before!

Comment: I think the website I am trying to scrape has too much Javascript, I do not know how to get around that.

Comment: Yes, the website has plenty of `script` elements. I would suggest you start scraping minimal content. For example, scrape only the title. After that, scrape the child of the topmost element. Once you will be familiar with the website, you can scrape more complicated contents.

Comment: I think I will try this one instead https://www.careeronestop.org/toolkit/training/find-scholarships.aspx?&curPage=1, seems a little easier, however, it doesn't have as much information. I sent them an email asking if they allow web scraping. Thank you for your help!